# Is it possible to require the C++ `override` specifier for virtual functions?

Tags: c++

Is there any current way, or possibly planned standards change, that would allow me to require an overridden virtual function use the `override` keyword?

```
class base {
    virtual void foo() = 0; //what, if anything, can I do here so that...
}

class derived {
    void foo(); //...this is an error...
    void foo() override; //...and only this accepted
}
```

Comment: g++ seems to have `-Wsuggest-override`.

Comment: @melpomene Excellent, thanks.

Comment: @RustyX Not an exact dupe. The other question is about Visual C++ 2012; this one is about the current (or future) C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature in C++.  You could enforce it with a static analysis tool, perhaps.